# Где правильнее сделать return true/false?

Tags: c#

Как вообще правильнее расставить блоки return/false в следующем блоке кода:

```
  public bool CheckIfDBIsExists() // selecting from pg_database and checking if DB from config is exists
    {
        NpgsqlConnection conn =
            new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=" + config.PGLogin + ";" +
                                 "Password=" + config.PGPass + ";");
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("PG Connected");
            string getlistofDBs = @"SELECT datname FROM pg_database; ";

            NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(getlistofDBs, conn);

            try
            {

                List<string> DBList = new List<string>();
                NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    DBList.Add(dr[0].ToString());

                }

                foreach (var db in DBList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("List of DBs:");
                    Console.WriteLine(db);
                }

                if (DBList.Contains(config.PGdbName))
                {
                    return true; // ?
                }
                else
                {
                    return false; // ?
                }

            }

            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

        }

        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

По идее если условие `DBList.Contains(config.PGdbName)` истинно, то мы должны вернуть `true`, но вопрос, как быть с false? Должен ли я `return false` пихать в каждый блок `catch` и нужен ли return в блоке `finally`?

Comment: `return` внутри `finally` Нельзя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в одном месте `true`, а при любых других исходах `false`, то возврат можно сделать в конце метода, так как если управление дошло до этого оператора, значит оно не дошло до `return true`.

```
public bool CheckIfDBIsExists() {
    ...
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Поставьте `return false;` в самом конце:

```
        if (DBList.Contains(config.PGdbName))
        {
            return true;
        }
        ...
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return false;
}
```